# In some cases, "come" and "go" are interchangeable, right?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

**Note**: This post is discussing **verbs**, the following scenario is to add background for discussion.

Let's say we are discussing the usage of adverbs.

> I
>   always wake up early
>
> he never gets angry

we could say

> always and never **go** in the mid position before the verb

we could also say

> always and never **come** in the mid position before the verb

Is my understanding right?

Although I got this sense, I don't know the rules clearly, in what situations, "come" and "go" are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come* and *go*, "intransitive verbs of motion" (in the words of the *OED*) **come** to us from Old English and thus have had over a millennium to develop a wide range of meaning and idiomatic usage. The *OED* catalogs about 70 major categories of meaning for *come* and over 90 for *go*. One basic difference between the two is that *come* signifies motion toward the speaker:

> Mr. Watson, **come** here. I want to see you

and *go* signifies either general motion or motion away from the speaker:

> **Go** away!

with "toward" and "away" having either literal of metaphorical meaning. I haven't done an exhaustive study, but I'd venture a guess that the two words are rarely interchangeable. In the first sentence of this answer, the word *come* means having a traceable forebearer in an ancestral or contributory language. *Go* may not be substituted:

> * The word **goes** to us from Old English.

In your example

> *always* and *never* **go** in the mid position before the verb

*go* means properly appear, and *come* may not be substituted.

Idiomatic usages are not interchangeable: you can "**go** crazy" (meaning descend into insanity) but not "**come** crazy," and you can "**come** to understand" (meaning gradually gain knowledge) but not "**go** to understand".

Likewise idiomatic expressions with prepositions are not interchangeable. For instance you can "**come** into money" (meaning inherit money), but not "**go** into money." On the other hand, you an "**go** into a subject" (meaning discuss the subject in detail), but not "**come** into a subject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does OED stand for Oxford English Dictionary?

Comment: Yes. I should have noted that I'm using the original printed edition. I didn't check the supplements for later tallies. And I don't have a subscription to the online version.