# Is "add background" an idiomatic expression?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I asked a question ([In some cases, "come" and "go" are interchangeable, right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238409/95044)) just now, and added some explanation at the beginning.

> This post is discussing verbs, the following scenario is to **add background** for discussion.

Is "add background" an idiomatic expression? Is there other beginning more appropriate for this kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic in the sense that it sounds natural, like what a native English speaker would say, but it's not an "idiomatic expression" in the sense of a formulaic phrase. For example, "hold your horses" is an idiomatic expression meaning "be patient."

Comment: Agreed. It is natural but uncommon. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=add+background+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3